# Press Enter Key behaves like a Tab in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, focus

I found the following:

```
$('body').on('keydown', 'input, select, textarea', function(e) {
    var self = $(this)
    , form = self.parents('form:eq(0)')
    , focusable
    , next
    ;
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible');
        next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this)+1);
        if (next.length) {
            next.focus();
        } else {
            form.submit();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

But how do I make that the next value has been highlighted ( behaves like as TAB)/

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
next.select();
```

.select() selects the content of your input box. You cant find more about .select() [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2009/04/select-text-in-input-box-on-user-select.html).

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TSc8E/45/).